# How do I tell how much space my applications use

Tags: apps, storage

My phone is usually pretty full and I don't really have much music or photos on it, so most of the space is used by probably over 100 applications I have installed. Is there a way to see which applications use most space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try going to settings and then to Storage Check. You get a nice sorted list at the end.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

P.S. I was looking for the same and passed by your question. I saw just now that it's over a year old. Perhaps this section was missing from settings back then?

Comment: You are correct, this was not available until this past summer.

Comment: Yes, it's a new fix to that problem. Now if it only had options to quickly uninstall apps or clear data of selected apps in that list... :)

Comment: What version exactly of WP does this require? It seems to be unavailable for 7.5 phones.

Comment: @Jessica Yang The [app's store page](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/storage-check/b4cf45cc-a355-40d2-8b74-51517a042a18) says it works with 8 and 8.1.

Answer (score 9):

You can't see the space used by apps directly, but in the Zune software you can see how much of used and reserved storage isn't media with the grey section of the storage gauge:

[image: Zune device storage]

This space includes apps, app data, emails, documents, and reserved storage. You can check and set how much reserved space you have on your device in Zune settings > Phone > Reserved space:

[image: Zune reserved space]

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but this does not help me. I already can see that my apps use most of the space available. What I want to see though is which app uses most space, so I can make decisions which apps to get rid of if I don't use them frequently.

Comment: I'm hoping there is at least some hacky app I could install on a dev-unlocked phone that would provide me that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Windows Phone Device Manager](http://www.touchxperience.com/) may allow you to do this.

It requires an unlocked phone, which I have, but I have not tried it out myself yet.  When I last looked at it, the last release was pre-Mango, but it seems to have been updated now.