# Is it possible to see a breakdown of the reserved space and other content?

Tags: storage

Zune on my laptop shows that I have a huge 3.26 GB of space taken up by this category of items. This seems disproportionately large - I do not recall installing so many apps, and the reserved space comes in at only 5%, or around 400MB, so I'm left to wonder where else these space have gone to.

[image]

Is it possible to see this a breakdown of what's in this category?

**Related:** [How do I tell how much space my applications use](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-do-i-tell-how-much-space-my-applications-use)

Comment: Related: [How to understand reserved space and the storage usage graph?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/880/how-to-understand-reserved-space-and-the-storage-usage-graph)

Answer (score 4):

There is no tool that will let you discern the exact content due to the nature of isolated storage (this is how the phone's OS, Silverlight, stores information). One thing you should be aware of, is whatever space an individual app uses is inside that bar.

For instance, you could have an RSS reader that stores all of the items you've ever read, or a multimedia app that saves video/music, it will here displayed here mixed with all the other apps' isolated storage.

If you're looking to free some of that up, think about an app you may have that would be storing data on top of it's own size and is cumulative. Go into the app, clear out any extra stuff you don't need and notice the bar drop significantly.

Comment: For example, nokia drive (the Nokia mapping app) downloads the maps to the phone for offline usage. that would be in the storage

Comment: Great example, Joe! Maps are big data items. Make sure you only download what you'll use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't Think it's possible to see a breakdown of the "Reserved content"
I do know what it might be :)

You see, the reserved content could be:

1. Apps
2. Apps content (Like songs in spotify)
3. Emails and attachments
4. Might be more stuff but i don't remember any more…

The biggest space stealer is emails I think.

Someone else that knows what more is in this category? :)

Comment: Emails do not need to take up much space at all.  There is a setting for how many days are kept on the phone - the rest are just downloaded as headers, or are searchable on the server.

Comment: PDF files can be quite large, and would fall into this category.

Answer (score 1):

Reserved space includes space for apps as well as space where guest computers can store content. You can manage how much reserved space there is in the settings screen for the phone in Zune, but I don't know of any way to visualize what is in it, except for turning on the phone and looking at what's installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are watching a lot of video. I think there are save in the storage space, no doubt you can't review it. Do a reset and the memory will go back to normal.

Comment: How do you know that the original poster is watching a lot of video? whilst that is one cause, it is not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I connected the phone and ran Zune as a different user account, it would forget how the space was divided up. When I connected it again and ran Zune under the original user account, previously where it was broken down into videos/photos/music, it was all shown as Reserved space and other content.