# Is there a utility equivalent of 'Disk Cleanup' for Windows Phone 7? does the phone fragment?

Tags: settings, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to see a breakdown of the reserved space and other content?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-it-possible-to-see-a-breakdown-of-the-reserved-space-and-other-content)

I am hitting the space limit on my wp7 device. I have tried to delete a few items, i.e. emails, photos,... but still it is complaining of space issue.

Do we have a utility that can scan the device and recover some noncontiguous/fragmented space?

Comment: Like Joe said the phone does not fragment space like an NTFS/FAT file system does [http://j.mp/KG4ia0 ]. @Joe I think there are enough phone users that worry or think this does happen to warrant keeping this question open. Leave an answer and i'll upvote it

Answer (score 3):

**Cleaning things up.**

There isn't really that much to clean up as compared to your computer. Most of this would depend on yourself than on to run some automated tool, some examples:

- Clear the history of the Internet Explorer.
- Get rid of older mails which you will never act on again.
- Uninstall applications you once installed but actually never need.
- Get rid of music, videos and photos that you tend to skip, because you don't wan't them anyway.

And if you want to get rid of any actual caching crap, you could consider resetting your phone each year and starting over. But I doubt if that's going to differ that much.

**Does fragmentation hurt here?**

Fragmentation is something known to be a bit noticeable on hard drives, but you won't really see this on your phone as it doesn't have a hard drive. Instead the phone uses what is called Flash Memory (think of a USB thumb drive, or SD card for your camera). Fragmentation isn't anything you need to worry about with this type of drive.

### To summarize what you could do:

1. Depending on your usage, do a weekly or monthly cleanup of history and older crap.
2. Do a yearly reset of your phone if you feel that it generated crap, fragmentation or other slug.

Comment: great answer, Tom. I added some more information under "Fragmentation" feel free to accept the edit only if you like the addition :)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not solve your particular free-space problem, I would recommend using OneDrive to store all of your documents and photos.

If you have a mobile plan with good speeds and generous bandwidth then you can keep all of your music on OneDrive and stream it as needed.

Some good tip and tricks [here](http://www.wpcentral.com/tips-tricks-skydrive-windows-phone).