# How to understand reserved space and the storage usage graph?

Tags: storage

In Zune, I have set the **Reserved space** setting for my phone to 5%.

However, when I look at the usage graph the reserved space is at over 50%.

[image: Windows Phone 7.1 storage usage as seen by Zune]

What exactly does that mean? How can I free some of it up?

Answer (score 3):

Probably easiest to just quote Microsoft on this:

> The Reserved space and other content section represents downloaded
>   apps and games, and content that was downloaded from other computers
>   and copied onto a player or phone.

There are three options to recover some of the reserved space:

- Adjust the space that's reserved on your device via Zune.
- Delete content from your device via Zune.
- Delete unwanted games or apps from your Windows Phone.

Full details can be found on the [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953593).

Comment: Oops, I didn't even notice the "other content" bit. Still seems strange since most of my apps are only a few megabytes.

Comment: @Louis if the app has saved data that that will be included. For example, the Nokia Drive app is very small itself, but once you download the map and voice data you have ~100MB used.

Comment: @Joe that makes sense. I've been trying though, and I really can't reconcile about 7GB of data. After deleting all of the apps I would consider storage hungry, clearing my IE history, and changing mail to only download the last three days, I've only freed up about 300MB. There's something strange about this "other content".

Comment: @Louis in Zune, did you try adjusting the reserved space percentage (step 2.a in the link)? What percent is it currently set to?

Comment: @row1 I've tried setting it to zero. It frees up about 675MB (sounds about right for 5% of a 13-14GB total capacity). So, it turns out the reserved space concept is pretty straight forward. A file explorer would really help, because between apps, their storage, games, Office documents and email, I just can't account for all that missing space.

Comment: I've got this with my phone, but it appears to be because I have copied music onto it via both my work and home PC - this can push the music to show as "reserved and other"