# Keeping track of application memory

Tags: storage

How to know which application is consuming what amount of memory on my phone. With only 2Gb of songs and approx 30-40 apps my phone shows 200 Mb left when connected to Zune. This is a pain. How to find out the culprit and remove that app?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13/106

Comment: its using zune. I am looking for exact memory usage without using zune. Like memory taken up by each app you have installed. 
There should be some mechanism.

Comment: The [accepted answer to the other question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/24/106) was effectively "**You can't measure by app**, best option is to monitor the overall usage"

Comment: hmm.. So there is no third party tool like windows phone manager or any other equivalent?

Comment: Apps are so tightly isolated from each other on the Windows Phone OS that apps can't even detect what other apps are installed, nor see the disk space used, other than what they've used.

Comment: Ohkay. Thanks for the information. But can you clear me about http://www.touchxperience.com/ these kind of softwares? Do they work. I tried it but it doesn't connect. Am I wasting my time?

Comment: That appears to only work for developer unlocked devices. Other desktop applications that behave similarly that I have seen have been unable to see the presence of apps installed via the Marketplace, but they may have found a way around that.

Comment: I have a dev unlocked device.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but right now there is no way to know this. The windows OS is a closed eco-system, in which the applications have control over their allocated space and memory and no one can access the others.

Currently, the phone memory and battery life are not accessible to the developers. These setting solely reside with the OS. In future update, you might expect this but not surely

Comment: ya i know that but is there any hack or third party software which can tell me this as my phone is dev unlocked.